# App won't connect to MongoDB using MongoDB code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I can run everything fine locally, and the app shows up on Heroku (all using the local mongoose db), but if I switch to the MongoDB db, using the code provided by MongoDB, both the local (goorm) and the Heroku sites fail when I do anything that needs to address the db.

The first err that appears in the Heroku log is:

```
2020-08-08T15:57:45.898855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed 
2020-08-08T15:57:46.903138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lit-forest-68974.heroku app.com request_id=a99ca76f-f8a8-4790-bf83-d42c24cc17d7 fwd="77.11.27.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-08T15:57:47.298492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lit-forest-68974.herokuapp.com request_id=cf828829-07cf-4c23-861f-3a123039a66f fwd="77.11.27.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protoco
l=https
```

I am thinking (hoping) that the issue is something in how I reference the db in my app.js file. I am using:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://NeilGreer:Ng232117@clearport1.sxp3s.mongodb.net/clearport11?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

Which was the code directly copied from MongoDB.'

Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: In case your `uri` variable contains your actual user/password please consider editing and removing those.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting H10 error.
No issues found on your MongoDB connect file as it is working well on local.

Please check below items.

1. Check whether you have added start script in package.json

   "scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js"
   }
2. Don't set PORT in your code. Heroku will automatically set PORT and can get from environmental variables.

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
3. Also check your Procfile whether web dyno commands given correctly.